# How do I make my D3 collapsible chart, collapsible?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nodes, hierarchical

I've created this hierarchical chart using D3 and I want to make it collapsible. I'm prety new to D3 so I'm just getting used to understanding the code. I also need the width between the nodes to increase but I don't know how to do this. Currently the text overlaps eachother which is why I need to expand the width between each node. Can someone also help with this too?

**D3 code:**

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  root = treeData[0];

  update(root);

  function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Length of the link
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

    // Declare the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // Enter the nodes.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
      });

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; 
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Declare the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter the links.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  }
```

Comment: what does treeData[0]; look like?

Comment: kindly also share the JSON on which your code is working on..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Mike Bostock's work on Collapsible Tree will help http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

You can observe that adding collapse function, and attaching mouse events to nodes is what enables nodes to be collapsible.

You would also want to add codes involving nodeExit and nodeUpdate.

To fix the problem of texts overlapping one another - observe your code for the part where you append text to nodeEnter.

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; 
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

Play around with the numbers for -18 : 18. Increasing those numbers may help texts to not overlap with one another, as those numbers adjust the distance of texts and nodes. You may also want to play around with "text-anchor". Try this instead:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr('class', 'nodeText')
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);
```

Lastly, if you really want to understand D3 tree fully, this link is a phenomenal source http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html

Comment: Good explanation thumbs up